# Use laptop as second monitor for another laptop

Tags: vga, laptop-display

Scenario: driving to tampa, have two laptops (win 7 and win xp) and vga to vga cord (the blue one used to connect pc's to their monitor)
Screen on win7 laptop is broken to the point of no visibility.
I want the win xp laptop to show the win 7 laptop's screen. Is there a program i can download or a setting in the control panel to do this?

Comment: Could use VNC plus an ethernet cross over cable

Comment: Check out this guide on using your laptop as a second screen: http://symless.com/synergy/second-screen

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that if you haven't got a VIDEO-IN adapter which, usually, isn't provided on a laptop.

Comment: you can use remote desktop to do this. Not using his vga cable, but an ethernet cable should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of either VNC or remote desktop to do this. You'd need to form a network between the two machines, either using a crossover cable or a switch.

You may (should) find a normal ethernet cable might do the job also as a lot of equipment is auto-sensing for crossover situations these days and fixes the issue software side.

Getting remote desktop turned on or VNC installed without a monitor is your real issue. You're best bet is to plug an external monitor into the broken laptop, install VNC or enable remote desktop, and connect to it from the first laptop over a network connection. From that point on the external monitor is no longer needed.

But no, you can't connect a vga cable to the video-out port on your laptop and hope to stream video into it. It just doesn't work that way.